# PDF as output in rest API

Tags: c#, pdf

I have this HTTP api

```
http://localhost:1111/myApi/Test
```

and that supports JSON and xml as outout format. How can I get pdf as output?

I am using itext and the following code. It does gives me pdf back but stores in root directory of the application. How can I get the pdf open in new window and ask for Open or save dialogue. I am using Chrome Rest Client to test.

```
     public void Generatepdf (string content)
        {

           Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("pdfResponses.pdf",                                                     FileMode.Create));

 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=someReport.pdf");

        document.Open();        
        document.Add(new Paragraph(content));
        document.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Will: this is not Servlet code. Look like sort of .NET. user1224171: please insert appropriate language tags, not just "rest" and "api".

Comment: This is C# code and I meant for RESTFUL api. I was wondering how that got changed.

Comment: Will Hartung made a wrong edit. I've rectified it. But in the future you really need to be more specific about the language you're using. This site is not for only C#. In any way, to fix this "problem" you should just replace `new FileStream()` by the output stream of the HTTP response.

Comment: @BalusC:  replacing  new FileStream() by the output stream of the HTTP response gives me some messy binary stuff in my output window.

Comment: He mentioned iText, I didn't know there was a C# implementation of iText. This has nothing to do with the REST architecture, it's simply an HTTP request. Not all HTTP requests are REST requests, and, either way, the REST architecture is not germane to this question about how to serve up a PDF over a C# HTTP response. Perhaps this is WCF question or something of that nature, I'm not that familiar with .NET.

Comment: @user1224171: that's exactly how a PDF file look like when treated as character data instead of binary data :) Perhaps you've passed a stream which is supposed to only take character data, or the content type header isn't properly been set.  Well, C# is completely beyond me. Good luck.

Comment: There is this iTextSharp for .net